# Most impactful optimisations to improve transaction finality on solana?

Tags: solana-program, transactions, instructions, performance

I would like my application to have the transaction finality similar to "break" solana game. "break" does several optimisations to achieve the speeds it does as stated here - https://github.com/solana-labs/break. However it does not state how impactful each of the optimisations are.

Here is the list of optimisations -

1. A service to forward transactions directly to the TPU UDP port of the current cluster leader.
2. Creating accounts ahead of time.
3. Subscribing to account updates instead of transaction signatures

Any idea by how much each optimisation will improve transaction finality? Are there any optimisations I have missed?

Please share your thoughts!

Answer (score 3):

Hey I am currently working on the same topic for a game.

1. I have not yet figured out.
2. Totally makes sense and then only update the account data.
3. The biggest improvements I saw came from using socket connection to listen to account updates instead of getting the data via RPC
   https://docs.solana.com/de/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#accountsubscribe

In most cases you do not need to wait for finality but instead you can just wait for the first confirmation.
So you can set the confirmation status on all RPCs to confirmed.
Then getting confirmed block hash instead of finalized and also setting the web socket connection to confirmed.

Like this you can get one account update per roughly 400ms and it gets pushed to all clients via socket.

When there is bad performance on Solana it can happen though that some your transactions do not get finalized. I didn't run into this problem yet though.

Here is a video on how it looks like in the game:
https://twitter.com/SolPlay_jonas/status/1600292531513614337?s=20&t=camuwgargiF1Vl5yzjP3Xw

Comment: Wow thats impressive!